# PSD importation library that retains shapes as vectors?

Tags: python, graphics, photoshop, vector-graphics, psd

I have sifted through [many PSD libraries](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=psd) without success, so far, of finding any that actually import shapes as vectors.  All importation appears to result in bitmaps, which of course is limiting when you need to retain the ability to edit the content.

Are there any existing resources that will facilitate retention of vectors from Photoshop PSDs?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging an found some interesting things regarding this topic that perhaps others might find interesting as well, particularly for one option on the Python front:

This is specifically regarding a Python package for reading Adobe Photoshop PSD files called [`psd-tools`](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools)

I asked the author about retention of vector data such that it will import shapes as vectors.  The response was exceptionally helpful and enlightening:

> `psd-tools` doesn't discard vector path data, but this data is not
>   decoded - what you get is a binary blob and an ID that says the data
>   is a path data. It should be straightforward to implement the decoding
>   because the format is [**documented by Adobe**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_17587), but this is not
>   implemented yet.
>
> As far as the effort that would be required, it should take a couple
>   hours if the specs are correct and complete; if specs are missing
>   something or there are hidden pitfalls it could take up to a couple of
>   days. (Add a time for a developer to get familiar with the codebase
>   and with PSD specs. I won't have time to implement it myself anytime
>   soon, but ***I can review a pull request - pull requests are
>   welcome!***)
>
> There are 3 "layers" in psd-tools: reader, decoder and user API.
>   Reader works with vector data already; what I described above are
>   steps to make decoder work with it. The goal of decoder is to convert
>   raw data to data structures that closely follow the original data
>   format, but are readable from Python - e.g. convert binary blob to a
>   namedtuple. To get a nice user API for vector data more efforts could
>   be needed, but decoder data could be useful by itself even if it is a
>   bit low-level.

The original discussion may be found here: https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools/issues/35